# Windows Installer in XML custom actions

Tags: c#, windows, wix

How to link a C# dll to a WiX program using custom action.
I am new to WiX so I tried what I could.

I used the following tags.

```
<Binary Id="Uninstall"   SourceFile="..\..\uninstaller.dll"/>
<CustomAction Id="UNINSTALLER" BinaryKey="Uninstall" DllEntry="ManagedInstall" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>
```

and

```
<Custom Action="Uninstall" Sequence="1699" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
```

This is not working; not even close. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: More information is needed here. First of all, you are setting both the "Sequence" and "After" attributes in your <Custom> element. These attributes are mutually exclusive with each other, and should cause compilation to fail.

Furthermore, what is "not working"? Is the MSI building correctly, or is there an error during install? If there is an error during install, then you'll want to provide the relevant snippet from the MSI's install log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call easily call managed code from an installer.  This article describes the steps required: [Creating Custom Action for WIX Written in Managed Code without Votive](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132918/Creating-Custom-Action-for-WIX-Written-in-Managed)